# Safari won't open FTP link

Tags: ftp, safari

I have a link, ftp://testuser:testpass@myip/test/test.html

When that link is opened in Safari on either MacOS or iOS, it gives me an "unknown error" (NSURLErrorDomain: -1) and fails to load.

It works without a problem in Chrome on MacOS.

Any wisdom?

Comment: Does ftp work in Safari if you just go to `ftp://myip` and then enter username and password in the prompt?

Comment: I found a duplicate question https://superuser.com/q/1276854/141595 It appears Apple has disabled FTP with credentials in Safari in newer versions of the (i)OS.

Comment: Okay, interesting.  Thank you for the inspiration.  It doesn't work that way, but I tried ftp://speedtest.tele2.net and it took me right in on mobile Safari (which is what I really care about)...just seeing second comment, that's really frustrating, but thank you again